# Does having `const` and non-`const` versions of a member function qualify as overloading?

Tags: c++

Is declaring a `const` and non-`const` member function with the same name classified as overloading?

```
iterator find ( const key_type& x );
const_iterator find ( const key_type& x ) const;
```

Comment: There's no question here.  Why are there 3 upvotes?

Comment: Are you asking if these two functions are overloads?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I can make out the question "Is it overloading to declare both `const` and non-`const` member functions with the same name?"

Comment: Yes. The const version will be selected for const `this`, and the non-const version will be selected for non-const `this`.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid example of function overloading.  If that's the question.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Apparently, Vikdor disagrees with you.  I see no reason to believe that your interpretation is more accurate than his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is overloading. The term is defined in `[over]/1` as:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be overloaded.

Here, there are clearly two different declarations with the same name.

Comment: Additionally, that kind of `const` is part of the function's signature.